# Liouville's Theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: distribution-theory

Liouville's Theorem states that if a tempered distribution is harmonic, $\Delta{u}=0$, then $u$ is given by a polynomial. For the argument, we take Fourier transform of $\Delta{u}=0$ to obtain $4\pi^2|\xi|^2\hat{u}=0$. I do not understand why this should imply that $\hat{u}$ has support in $\{0\}$. I should be able to conclude that if a Schwartz class function $\phi$ is supported away from $0$, then $\hat{u}(\phi)=0$. But all we have is $\hat{u}(|\xi|^2\phi)=0$. 
In fact, any polynomial which is non-zero other than at zero would do the job and not only $|\xi|^2$.

I am surely missing something tiny.

Comment: Here is a proof: http://books.google.it/books?id=HMpb9pLvIikC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=liouville+theorem+tempered+distributions&source=bl&ots=UbAncsjJW3&sig=8VGQslrK284kDhDiPKWfuqAWAik&hl=it#v=onepage&q=liouville%20theorem%20tempered%20distributions&f=false